# Insert formula in specific column of certain sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Here is the scenario:
When ever there is value "1" in column A of Sheet 1 i want to insert formula "=UNIQUE(Sheet2!B2:B1000)" in column B of Sheet 1.

I have only this formula which is used to delete contents:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if(e.range.columnStart === 1) { 
e.range.offset(0,1).clearContent();
}
}
```

but I am not able to insert formula based on a cell value

Comment: By column B of Sheet 1, you mean `'Sheet 1'!B1`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet1'){ return; }
  if(e.range.columnStart==1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setFormula("=UNIQUE(Sheet2!B2:B1000)");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the error is coming "Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "insert form""

Comment: Did you add the 'e' parameter? And perhaps you need to change your sheet name.

Comment: @RonyJoseph It's not possible to run `onEdit(e)` from the Apps Script editor, you should use another function that pass the `e` argument with the required properties.

Comment: @rubén, is there any other script for my case?

Comment: If you mean how to test `onEdit(e)` please checkout [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

To insert a formula that uses A1 notation use `setFormula`. This is a method of Class Range, meaning that you first should get the range where you want to put your formula. There are several ways to get a range. Please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/